# Generalized Stokes theorem applied to Tensor Moments

Tags: differential-geometry

I am working with geometry and need to calculate 0th, 1st and 2nd moments in polyhedra, its polygons and its lines.

From a previous answer in this forum, I understand that p-moments are:

$ M^p = \int_\Omega{\vec{x}^{\otimes p}}d\Omega $

which is a tensor of rank p.

Because I want to avoid volume and surface integrals and so perform only line integrals, I want to apply Stokes theorem:

$\int_{\partial \Omega} w = \int_\Omega dw$

I understand that the price to pay will be to compute higher order moments, like in the divergence theorem:

$ \int_V x_i^2 dV = \frac{\hat{n_i}}{3}\int_{S}x_i^3dS$

However, my question is: How can I take the step forward and go down to the line integral? And, most important, how can I establish such a relationship in a general way for a general rank tensor?

I can assume that my space is  $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean $\int \otimes^p x d\Omega$?

Comment: I mean a tensor power, like this [Tensor Power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_powers_and_braiding) I guess that they are equivalent notations.

Comment: Ah right. The $\otimes$ should be part of the superscript.

Comment: You are right! I corrected that already. Thanks for your comment! ;)